# Magento site restoration

Tags: magento, backup, restore

I have a situation where I had to restore my magento site from an FTP backup which I made earlier of all the files and folders of the `public_html` directory. Note that I don't have a mySql backup.

Now when I try to visit my `www.domainname.com` site, it just displays an error number. Note that I can no longer go to `www.domainname.com/admin`.  I do not know how to enable debug logging so I can see what the error number is trying to tell me.  However, I can go to my `hostgator.com` control panel and click on the error logs, but there are no entries.

My question is:  is there any way I can salvage the original site, minus the database?  I'm okay with having to re-enter products, etc., that I once had into the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The site is 85% the database. No database backup, no site.

You must backup both your public_html files and your Magento database to fully back up your Magento e-commerce installation.

Basically all you have is the application, code changes, skin and templates from the previous version.

Configuration, CMS pages, categories, product and all the rest live in the database.

The error number displayed is the file name of a stack trace that ends up in var/report. It's probably telling you that no database exists at this point.

Comment: @Mark : with ref to above answer , check the file error log in var/report (the file name will contain your error number) .By opening the file only the top few lines will give u a hint about the error that may help you to find the solution.